# Is it possible to create infinite scroll inside of articles on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I haven't seen such a thing in the wild, but is it possible to create infinity scrolling inside of article pages on WordPress?
Meaning, in case a user is on an article and he keeps on scrolling down, is it possible to send him to the next article chronologically without having him press anything - just by him hitting the bottom part of the page?
Is there a more elegant way besides redirecting the user inside of this kind of JS function?

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    // you're at the bottom of the page
    }
};
```

I'm trying to think about the best user experience as well.

Comment: It's possible, yes. You need to use AJAX for that. If you google "wordpress load article ajax" you will find lots of information on that.

Comment: @ChrisG My two questions regarding it are if it works inside of articles as well, and how should I approach it because I don't want to overload WordPress too much.

Comment: Maybe this example could help you: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qjjLpX

Comment: Why wouldn't it work inside articles? And what do you mean by "overload"? Implementing it requires writing a bunch of code and adding it to a theme, at which point do you consider it "overloaded"? I don't mean to sound rude, but I don't understand what your actual question is. It sounds like you're just looking for somebody to hand you a perfect solution.

Comment: Do you mean 'send him to the next article' in the same sense as if the user had clicked a Next button, or do you mean giving a scroll effect where the next post gets loaded below, header, featured image, widgets, menus etc and all? or....

Comment: @ChrisG All good, you're not being rude at all. I'm not looking for a perfect solution, I only trying to figure what is the best way to approach it. I'll try to specify my questions: By overloading I meant how I control the requests that are sent to wordpress/server. We had incidents even on our homepage that bots kept scrolling and crashed our server so we put a limit on it. I know it's "infinite" scrolling by definition, but I just don't want it to slow the website in any way. Regarding the "inside of articles" question: I meant if it's possible to make such infinite WP_Query in articles.

Comment: I see; any wordpress page allows AJAX requests, whether it's based on single.php or not. And any AJAX request can do arbitrary things server-side.

Comment: @AHaworth What I have in mind right now is that the next article (as pressed by "next" button) would pop up under the original article on the same page along with its headline, images etc.
Another concern I have is about analytics: How can I keep the views count of each article if it's loaded on the same page?